# ActionScript: Insert text in string at random places?

Tags: string, actionscript

I'm building an ActionScript program in which I need to insert text into another string at random positions.
I have the text which strings will be inserted into; and I have the strings which will be inserted as an array.
However, I don't know how to go about inserting the elements of this array into the other string at random positions.
 Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your modified question:

```
var stringsToInsert:Array = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
var text:String = "here is some text"

var textArr:Array = text.split(" ");

while(stringsToInsert.length)
{
    var randomPosition:uint = Math.round( Math.random() * textArr.length );
    textArr.splice(randomPosition, 0, stringsToInsert.pop());
}
text = textArr.join(" ");
trace(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(arrayOftringsToInsert.length)
{
  var randomPosition:uint = Math.round( Math.random() * text.length )
  text = text.slice(0, randomPosition) + arrayOftringsToInsert.pop() + text.slice(randomPosition + 1, text.length)
}
```

Comment: it almost worked. it inserted words splitting full words. what i really wanted was to insert before and after complete words. if some of you can help it will be awesome. still thank you user531694

Comment: Technically, this exactly satisfies the description of functionality you provided. To insert at word boundaries, you would need to split the text string on the space character, and modify the randomPosition constraints to generate a random index value in your target text array, inserting random values, then joining the array back into a string. Use this API: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29